# Where Cache stored in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the Cache object to store the Datatable.
like as below

```
Cache["dt"]=dtsum;
```

If I store like this where cahce will store either at client side or serverside.
Previoulsy I was storing in Viewstate. But I was thinking of Viewstate that store data in page itself. so I'm storing in Cache. which will be better option.
please suggest me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Cache` is stored in web server memory.

You should understand the differences between `Viewstate`, `Cache` and `Session`

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PTCacheSessionViewState.aspx

Comment: Thanks which will be the best. To store data obejcts. I think webserver memory means at server side.

Comment: Its just a doubt. Didn't mean to oppose. If the cache is storing in the web server, then how could it be more faster when fetching data? Still the server call is needed and the n/w traffic is there. right?

Answer (score 0):

Cache stores the data at Server Side.

Upto.NET Framework 3.5 SP1, you had only one option that is it by default used to store in memory (In Proc).. With .NET 4, You have an option to store your cache outside as well using CacheProviders...